# Switching to a new view display an image which is randomly selected

Tags: iphone

My goal is that when I switch to a new view, a random image is selected via the `arc4random` function and displayed in the view instantaneously.

Can some one give me direction on how to achieve the instant execution of random function selection process with out a button to prompt the random function process?
Any examples of code, were should the code be placed, etc.

Comment: Wow, that was a long sentence... too much for my organic parser!

Comment: Apologies are no use if you don't go back and try and fix the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

You can put your image selecting code in this function and when the nib is created and loaded control will pass to it.

Alternatively, you can use

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

To have the image appear fresh each time you make the view visible.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Try putting it in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear.

See also: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Also, FYI, you will get more answers to your questions if the questions themselves are readable. It took me a couple of parses to understand your problem. Try spell checking and adding some grammar, you'd be amazed at the difference it'll make.